# VHDL synthesis warning FF/Latch has a constant value of 0

Tags: warnings, vhdl, synthesis

I'm trying out some code that essentially involves using an FPGA and reading values from a temperature sensor.

The code is below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity ds18b20 is
    Port ( clk      : in  STD_LOGIC;        --50Mhz oscillator onboard
       dq       : inout  STD_LOGIC;
       temp_h : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       temp_l : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
          temperature   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0));
end ds18b20;

architecture Behavioral of ds18b20 is

--RESET  :  RESET AND PRESENCE PULSE
--CMD_CC :  SKIP ROM [CCh]
--WRITE_BYTE   :  WRITE SCRATCHPAD COMMAND
   --WRITE_LOW
   --WRITE_HIGH
--READ_BIT  :  

TYPE STATE_TYPE is     (RESET,CMD_CC,WRITE_BYTE,WRITE_LOW,WRITE_HIGH,READ_BIT,CMD_44,WAIT800MS,CMD_BE,GET_TMP,WAIT4MS); 
signal STATE: STATE_TYPE:=RESET; 

signal clk_temp : std_logic:='0'; 
signal clk1m : std_logic; 


signal write_temp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0'); 

signal TMP : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0); 
signal tmp_bit : std_logic; 

signal WRITE_BYTE_CNT : integer range 0 to 8:=0; 
signal WRITE_LOW_CNT : integer range 0 to 2:=0; 
signal WRITE_HIGH_CNT : integer range 0 to 2:=0; 
signal READ_BIT_CNT : integer range 0 to 3:=0; 
signal GET_TMP_CNT : integer range 0 to 12:=0; 

signal cnt : integer range 0 to 100001:=0; 
signal count : integer range 0 to 25:=0; 

signal WRITE_BYTE_FLAG : integer range 0 to 4:=0; 

begin 

ClkDivider: process (clk) 
            begin 
            if rising_edge(clk) then 
                if (count = 24) then 
                    count <= 0; 
                    clk_temp<= not clk_temp; 
                else 
                    count <= count +1; 
                end if; 
            end if;  
            clk1m<=clk_temp; 
            end Process; 


STATE_TRANSITION:   process(STATE,clk) 
                    begin 
                    if rising_edge(clk) then 
                        case STATE is 

                            --Master issues RESET pulse
                            when RESET=> 
                                if (cnt>=0 and cnt<500) then 
                                    dq<='0'; 
                                    cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                    STATE<=RESET;

                                --Master waits for PRESENCE pulse
                                elsif (cnt>=500 and cnt<1000) then 
                                    dq<='Z'; 
                                    cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                    STATE<=RESET; 
                                elsif (cnt>=1000) then 
                                    cnt<=0; 
                                    STATE<=CMD_CC;              -- SKIP ROM COMMAND STATE
                                end if; 

                            when CMD_CC=>                       -- SKIP ROM COMMAND
                                write_temp<="11001100";     -- SKIP ROM BINARY COMMAND
                                STATE<=WRITE_BYTE;             -- modified here

                            --Master issues write scratchpad command
                            when WRITE_BYTE=> 
                                case WRITE_BYTE_CNT is 
                                    when 0 to 7=> 
                                        if (write_temp(WRITE_BYTE_CNT)='0') then 
                                            STATE<=WRITE_LOW; 
                                        else 
                                            STATE<=WRITE_HIGH; 
                                        end if; 
                                            WRITE_BYTE_CNT<=WRITE_BYTE_CNT+1; 
                                    when 8=> 
                                        if (WRITE_BYTE_FLAG=0) then -- ????0XCC?? 
                                            STATE<=CMD_44;          --CONVERT TEMPERATURE
                                            WRITE_BYTE_FLAG<=1; 
                                        elsif (WRITE_BYTE_FLAG=1) then --?0X44?? 
                                            STATE<=RESET; 
                                            WRITE_BYTE_FLAG<=2; 
                                        elsif (WRITE_BYTE_FLAG=2) then --????0XCC?? 
                                            STATE<=CMD_BE;          -- READ SCRATCHPAD
                                            WRITE_BYTE_FLAG<=3; 
                                        elsif (WRITE_BYTE_FLAG=3) then --?0XBE?? 
                                            STATE<=GET_TMP; 
                                            WRITE_BYTE_FLAG<=0; 
                                        end if; 
                                        WRITE_BYTE_CNT<=0; 
                                end case; 

                                when WRITE_LOW=> 
                                    case WRITE_LOW_CNT is 
                                        when 0=> 
                                            dq<='0'; 
                                            if (cnt=78) then 
                                                cnt<=0; 
                                                WRITE_LOW_CNT<=1; 
                                            else 
                                                cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                            end if; 
                                        when 1=> 
                                            dq<='Z'; 
                                            if (cnt=2) then 
                                                cnt<=0; 
                                                WRITE_LOW_CNT<=2; 
                                            else 
                                                cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                            end if; 
                                        when 2=> 
                                            STATE<=WRITE_BYTE; 
                                            WRITE_LOW_CNT<=0; 
                                        when others=>WRITE_LOW_CNT<=0; 
                                    end case; 

                                    when WRITE_HIGH=> 
                                     case WRITE_HIGH_CNT is 
                                         when 0=> 
                                             dq<='0'; 
                                             if (cnt=8) then 
                                                 cnt<=0; 
                                                 WRITE_HIGH_CNT<=1; 
                                             else 
                                                 cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                             end if; 
                                         when 1=> 
                                             dq<='Z'; 
                                             if (cnt=72) then 
                                                 cnt<=0; 
                                                 WRITE_HIGH_CNT<=2; 
                                             else 
                                                 cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                             end if; 
                                         when 2=> 
                                             STATE<=WRITE_BYTE; 
                                             WRITE_HIGH_CNT<=0; 
                                         when others=>WRITE_HIGH_CNT<=0; 
                                    end case; 

                                    when READ_BIT=> 
                                        case READ_BIT_CNT is 
                                             when 0=> 
                                                 dq<='0'; 
                                                 if (cnt=4) then 
                                        READ_BIT_CNT<=1; 
                                        cnt<=0; 
                                                 else 
                                                     cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                                 end if; 
                                             when 1=> 
                                                 dq<='Z'; 
                                                 if (cnt=4) then 
                                                     READ_BIT_CNT<=2; 
                                                     cnt<=0; 
                                                 else 
                                                     cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                                 end if; 
                                             when 2=> 
                                                 TMP_BIT<=dq; 
                                                 if (cnt=1) then 
                                                     READ_BIT_CNT<=3; 
                                                     cnt<=0; 
                                                 else 
                                                     cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                                 end if; 
                                             when 3=> 
                                                 if (cnt=45) then 
                                                     cnt<=0; 
                                                     READ_BIT_CNT<=0; 
                                                     STATE<=GET_TMP; 
                                                 else 
                                                     cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                                 end if; 
                                             when others=>READ_BIT_CNT<=0; 
                                         end case; 

                                        when CMD_44=>                    -- CONVERT TEMPERATURE
                                             write_temp<="01000100";        -- CONVERT TEMPERATURE BINARY COMMAND
                                             STATE<=WRITE_BYTE; 

                             when WAIT800MS=> 
                                             if (cnt>=100000) then 
                                                 STATE<=RESET; 
                                                 cnt<=0; 
                                             else 
                                                 cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                                 STATE<=WAIT800MS; 
                                             end if; 

                                        when CMD_BE=>                       -- READ SCRATCHPAD
                                             write_temp<="10111110";      -- READ SCRATHPAD BINARY COMMAND
                                             STATE<=WRITE_BYTE; 

                             when GET_TMP=> 
                                             case GET_TMP_CNT is 
                                                 when 0 to 11=> 
                                                     STATE<=READ_BIT; 
                                                     TMP(GET_TMP_CNT)<=TMP_BIT; 
                                                     GET_TMP_CNT<=GET_TMP_CNT+1; 
                                                 when 12=> 
                                                     GET_TMP_CNT<=0; 
                                                     STATE<=WAIT4MS; 
                                            end case; 

                                            when WAIT4MS=> 
                                                 if (cnt>=4000) then 
                                                     STATE<=RESET; 
                                                     cnt<=0; 
                                                 else 
                                                     cnt<=cnt+1; 
                                                     STATE<=WAIT4MS; 
                                                 end if; 
                                                when others=>STATE<=RESET; 
                                            end case; 
                                        end if; 
                                    end process; 

                                    temp_h<='0'&TMP(11 downto 5); 
                                    temp_l<="0000"&TMP(4 downto 1); 
                                    temperature <= TMP;

end Behavioral;
```

The warning I get is

```
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <write_temp_0> has a constant value of 0 in block     <ds18b20>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <Mtridata_dq> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <ds18b20>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

write_temp is a variable that holds the binary commands for the sensor. So essentially, I will be sending these commands to the sensor via the "dq" bidirectional port. Now, the warning states that write_temp is always 0 which means I can't instruct the sensor to do any operation at all since its always 0.

Could anyone please shed some light on how to overcome this?
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here. The warning says that `write_temp_0` is always 0 - that is, the warning only applies to bit 0 of `write_temp`, not the other 7 bits.

This is to be expected, as you never set bit 0 of `write_temp` to be anything but 0. The synthesizer picks up on this, and optimizes it by simply trimming it to be a constant 0 instead of being connected to logic.

So try out the code and see if it works - if it doesn't, it's probably due to other reasons.

Also, when writing and verifying code like this, the simulator is a fantastic tool - it'll allow you to locate logic errors in your code very easily. So no reason not to get to know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

dear same problem i am  facing same problem running my code on fir, i have run your code it synthesis but due to warning it show's undefined values of your input and clk, don't assign 0 value, try to put different value like write_temp 7 to 1. i am not full expert of vhdl but when i make this change similar way i get over these warning, hope this work for you also.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, this warning (FF/Latch) occurs when we forget to assign some value for some signals  (or even maybe we think that it is not necessary to assign some value),  especially when there are some conditions like if-else. It is expected that for all conditions we assign a value. So, it makes our code neatly and also long to repeat some assignment in every condition,  but we can set an initial value for all those signals (which the FF/Latch warning refers to them) exactly after begin of a process and before if rising-edge.
For example, in STATE_Transition procecc, between begin and if rising_edge, you should write write_temp <= (others=>'0').